# ¿Revisando una Api Rest encontré esta expresión alguien sabe para que la usan?

Tags: java, webservice, spring-boot, swagger

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Reading RFC", nickname = "Reading Rfc", notes = "Reading RFC", response = Response.class, tags = {"service", })    
@ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful operation", response = Response.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Unsuccessful request"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Destination not found"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 422, message = "Unprocessable Entity"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Unsuccessful request or wrong code") })
```

Answer (score -1):

Esas anotaciones pertenecen a `Swagger`, que son unos lineamientos para documentar la funcionalidad de nuestra `API` basados en `OpenAPI`, de esta forma puedes configurar spring boot para que exponga la documentación tu API que se define a través de las anotaciones `@ApiResponses @ApiOperation` ademas puedes exponer una interfaz web desde la cual interactuar con la API sin la necesidad de programar un cliente, esto es útil de 2 maneras, 1 documentas la API mientras la creas y 2 los desarrolladores web y clientes que se conecten puede entender como función la API sin tener que ir al código fuente.
Puedes ver una demo a través de esta URL: https://petstore.swagger.io/?_ga=2.17745841.940416198.1595344208-461303050.1595344208